# How to update a bigquery row in golang

Tags: go, google-bigquery, gcloud

I have a go program connected to a bigquery table. This is the table's schema:

```
name    STRING  NULLABLE    
age     INTEGER NULLABLE    
amount  INTEGER NULLABLE
```

I have succeded at queryng the data of this table and printing all rows on console with this code:

```
ctx := context.Background()
client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, projectID)

q := client.Query("SELECT * FROM test.test_user LIMIT 1000")

it, err := q.Read(ctx)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
    for {
        var values []bigquery.Value
        err := it.Next(&values)
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            // TODO: Handle error.
        }
            fmt.Println(values)
    }
```

And I also have succeded to insert data on the table from a struct using this code:

```
type test struct {
    Name   string
    Age    int
    Amount int
}
u := client.Dataset("testDS").Table("test_user").Uploader()

savers := []*bigquery.StructSaver{
    {Struct: test{Name: "Jack", Age: 23, Amount:123}, InsertID: "id1"},
}

if err := u.Put(ctx, savers); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("rows inserted!!")
```

Now, what I am failing to do is updating rows. What I want to do is selecting all the rows and update all of them with an operation (for example: amount = amount * 2)

How can I achieve this using golang?

Comment: Please show your failing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating rows is not specific to Go, or any other client library. If you want to update data in BigQuery, you need to use [DML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language) (Data Manipulation Language) via SQL. So, essentially you already have the main part working (running a query) - you just need to change this SQL to use DML.

But, a word of caution: BigQuery is a OLAP service. Don't use it for OLTP. Also, there are [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#data_manipulation_language_statements) with using DML. Make sure you familiarise yourself with them.

Comment: so, considering that BigQuery is a OLAP. Do you think that a better aproach would be selecting all the rows from the table and creating a new table with the new updated column?

Comment: depends on the problem you're trying to solve, and what your env looks like. That said, we've used that approach many times - mainly for ELT and ad-hoc.